# Add existing recipient tabs to new document

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using DocuSign's rest API to add recipient signing tabs to documents using anchor strings (For example, 'DevSignHere'). But if we add another document later for the same recipient with the same anchor strings, DocuSign doesn't add those tabs on those anchor strings.

How can I tell DocuSign to 'look again' for anchor strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have added a new document then you need to call below API for the recipient to create new Tabs on the new document:

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs
```

[DS Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/create/)

Example:

```
POST /restapi/v2/accounts/<accountId>/envelopes/<envelopeId>/recipients/1/tabs

{
                           "dateSignedTabs": [
                              {
                                 "anchorString": "\\D1\\",
                                 "recipientId": "1",
                                 "tabLabel": "internal_date"
                              }
                           ],
                           "signHereTabs": [
                              {
                                 "anchorString": "\\S1\\",
                                 "recipientId": "1",
                                 "tabLabel": "internal_sign"
                              }
                           ],
                           "textTabs": [
                              {
                                 "anchorString": "\\T1\\",
                                 "recipientId": "1",
                                 "tabLabel": "internal_contact"
                              }
                           ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the new document's fields (Tabs) are managed by a template, then you can use Composite Templates to have the document "processed" by the right template. Ask this as a new question if you want to investigate this route.